# How to force \documentclass[]{article} to have 3 authors per row

Tags: formatting, author, author-number

I have a manuscript with 6 authors, and I am trying to place three authors in each row.

For example, this is the current code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{ The \textbackslash author macro should work with any number of
authors per row!}

\author{ AAA AAA\\ fff \and BBB BBB\\BLABLA \and CCC CCC\\BLABLA \and
DDD DDD\\ fff \and EEE EEE \\BLABLA \and FFF FFF\\BLABLA }

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This generates the following, while I'm trying to get DDD to move to the second row.

Any idea how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use any other packages, you should manually insert the appropriate adjustments between author C and D:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{A title}

\author{%
  Author A \\ Affiliation A \and
  Author B \\ Affiliation B \and
  Author C \\ Affiliation C
\end{tabular} \endgraf
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  Author D \\ Affiliation D \and
  Author E \\ Affiliation E \and
  Author F \\ Affiliation F
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The solution here stems from the fact that `\and` closes a preceding `tabular` and opens a new one when using `\author`. So, manual intervention allows you to insert a paragraph break (`\endgraf`).

You can also set your own style by suppling a `tabular` to `\author`:

```
\author{%
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
       Author A   &    Author B   &    Author C   \\
    Affiliation A & Affiliation B & Affiliation C \\
    \\
       Author D   &    Author E   &    Author F   \\
    Affiliation D & Affiliation E & Affiliation F
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Note that these TeX constructions might interfere with the PDF document properties if you're using packages that tap into `\author` to set that detail.